# XAMPP + OSX + Virtualhosts + change user in httpd.conf = phpmyadmin create database not working

Tags: mysql, macos, configuration, xampp, virtualhost

I have installed XAMPP on OSX Lion.
Because I want to serve a folder from one of my development folders I have added a virtualhost to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/myosxUsername/Documents/dir/dir/htdocs"
ServerName qmh
ErrorLog "logs/qmh-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/qmh-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and also added an entry to the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 qmh
```

Because of permission issue with the server accessing the directory `/Users/myosxUsername/Documents/dir/dir/htdocs` I have also changed the user in `httpd.conf` to my `myosxUsername`

```
User myosxusername
Group admin
# previous setting below
# User nobody
# Group nobody
```

After those changes virtual hosts work fine.
The problem is that when i now use phpmyadmin to create a new database i get the error message

> db_create.php: Missing parameter: new_db

if I change the user back to:

```
User nobody
Group nobody
```

then phpmyadmin works fine, but my virtualhost directory cannot be accessed due to permission issue.

I assume I somehow have to tell apache to not use the new user for mysql access somehow? Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See item 2.8 from phpMyAdmin FAQ (http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_2.8)

> - In the php.ini directive session.save_path and upload_tmp_dir, if these directories don't exist, are read-only or not accessable (f.e.
>     due to base_dir restrictions) this error will occur. See trk
>
>   - PHP installed from a packages (eg. an rpm) might set the permissions on these directories for an assumed user (eg. 'apache'). -
>       Users of other web servers, eg Lighttpd, may need to change the
>       ownership of these directories (eg. to 'lighttpd').
>   - On Windows, if PHP is using directories for session.save_path and upload_tmp_dir that are somewhere within the main "Temp"
>       directory, you must create those directories yourself; unlike other
>       Windows programs PHP will not create them itself.
> - If you are using Hardened-PHP (/suhosin patch) with the ini directive varfilter.max_request_variables set to the default (200) or
>     another low value, you could get this error if your table has a high
>     number of columns. Adjust this setting accordingly ( request limits,
>     thanks to Klaus Dorninger for the hint).
> - In config.inc.php, try to leave the $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] directive empty. See also FAQ 4.7.
> - Maybe you have a broken PHP installation or you need to upgrade your Zend Optimizer. See http://bugs.php.net/31134.
> - In the php.ini directive arg_separator.input, a value of ";" will cause this error. Replace it with "&;".

(tip from https://serverfault.com/questions/385465/phpmyadmin-missing-parameter)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the above ?

Comment: In php.ini: 'session.save_path = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/' and is read&writable by everybody

Comment: in php.ini 'arg_separator.input = "&"'

Comment: in php.ini 'upload_tmp_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/' and as stated above is Readable&Writable

Comment: I am wondering if I have to change ownership of '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/' currently system, admin, everyone has Read & Write permission

Comment: I am not sure where to fing `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']` in config.inc.php. I have looked in the phpmyadmin directory and that config file does not contain this directive

Comment: Thanks for your input @GabrielSantos. The solution to this still eludes me.